# Linux kernel internals using ARM architecture as reference

Tags: linux, kernel

Most of the linux kernel architecture books were written taking x86 architecture as reference (LKD by robert love or ULKI by bovett). Does there exist any book which explain linux kernel internals taking ARM architecture as reference.

Comment: what difference does it make to you? If you want a book recommendation perhaps state your intentions of learning instead. There may be a book, that is more suitable than the ones you mentioned/

Comment: Alex, thanks for your response.Yes my intentions is to learn low level linux routines on ARM. Can you mention the book name.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic questions are missing to really recommend you something and point you to useful resources:

- what low level routines do you mean?
- what are you going to do with that information?

The linux kernel is running on ARM already and most of the low level stuff is solved there and you shouldn't touch that unless you really know what you're doing. The linux kernel provides some generic low-level interfaces that its drivers stay portable without plattform specific snippets. Unless your intention is to add another ARM processor that is not supported yet you shouldn't need to dig around there.

If you want to add drivers or use components look into [this device tree howto](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-1).
One major difference to X86 is the device tree/ open firmware stuff because System on Chip devices have often the same hardware mapped to different memory.

If you are looking for embedded kernel development you might also look into [elinux](http://elinux.org/Main_Page).
Further reading is also provided in the [linux-kernel tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux-kernel/info) of stackoverflow.

Comment: @user3540117 everything that is part of `arch/arm/include/asm` everything that is required to implement kernel IPC, spinlocks, cache coherency stuff etc.